# Using a custom view page for image preview in Sonata Admin in Symfony 2 project

Tags: php, symfony, php-5.3, sonata-admin, sonata

I have the following admin system setup using Sonata Admin in my SF2 project. When I click "View Image" I want to show either a popup/overlay with the image, or if it's easier, a new page with the image. The route for this is configured as `/admin/ayrshireminis/gallery/galleryimage/{id}/view_image`

[image]

I have this method in my CRUDController which the codepath enters:

```
/**
 * preview the image
 *
 * @return RedirectResponse
 */
public function viewImageAction()
{
    // work out which image we are approving based on the ID in the URL
    $id = $this->get('request')->get($this->admin->getIdParameter());

    $object = $this->admin->getObject($id);

    // couldn't find the object
    if (!$object) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException(sprintf('unable to find the object with id : %s', $id));
    }

    return $this->render('SonataAdminBundle::empty_layout.html.twig', array('image' => $object));
```

}

How I can't find any Sonata documentation to work out howto simply display a blank page (within the Sonata Admin layout) with an image in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display a blank page with an image (within the Sonata Admin layout):

```
// src/ACME/YourBundle/Resources/views/empty_layout.html.twig
{% extends "SonataAdminBundle::standard_layout.html.twig" %}
{% block sonata_page_content %}
<img src="{{ image.src }}" />
{% endblock %}
```

And in your controller:

```
return $this->render('ACMEYourBundle::empty_layout.html.twig', array('image' => $object));
```

If you just want a blank page without the admin layout, same twig template but without extending sonata admin bundle's standard layout.